# Magento wsdl. Looking for a guide

Tags: magento

Well I am new in Magento Api theme, so I don't know how to create wsdl for api2. Any good guide will be appriciated.

**Added:**
What I need is:

1. How to write wsdl.xml in magento?
2. How magento will understand that if I type v2_soap? wsdl array then it should take mine version of wsdl.xml for my module?

Comment: You don't create the **WSDL**, you create a web service, the [W]eb [S]ervice [D]efinition [L]anguage is auto generated, what you probably trying to so is "How to consume a WDSL"... and btw, you should say, in what Language!

Comment: @balexandre, I have own module which, requires wsdl, but I didn't found any guide connected with magento web service. I already made V1 API which I use like $client->call('..method..','args'); And I want to create in my module API V2, so I can use something like $client->getAllRecentOrders(); or $client->createConfigurableProductsWithSizeANdColorOptions($data);

Comment: once again, you don't write WSDL ... you consume WSDL's, try to go to the link `http://domain.com/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl` ... remember to change `domain.com` and `magento` to your need. Ask something more plausible and with examples. **If you don't know what a WSDL is**, you shouldn't even doing this, ask someone to do it for you.

Comment: I am not a proffessional of wsdl, but I know what it is, how to use it and a little bit how to write it, but in a very little extend. Well if my question is so clumsy, what I need to know then: if I put wsdl.xml file to modules etc directory and if i create /model/product/api/v2.php with the same rules as wsdl.xml will it work or not? Will be accessable to world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found ca I was looking for:

[click](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-api-v2/)

*Update*

From comments below :

I'v managed to create v2 service, but it was more copying from catalog's wsdl.xml. But finally I'v managed to do what I asked ;)

Comment: next time ask how to extend the API, not how to change the definition file!

Comment: @balexandre, Please don't be soo offensive. Next time you'd better read the questions in very first post. And moreover I don't want to extend existing API. I want to write my own **wsdl.xml**

Comment: here you go again, you DO NOT write **WSDL** its an automatic process! read more!

Comment: @balexandre, Please don't be so nervouse. If you can read and I guess you can, I wrote that I need to know how to write **a physical file which is in modules etc folder and which name is *wsdl.xml* **.** So I asked You about how to write this file several times. Moreover if I don't create wsdl.xml for WSDL, my Java or C# client won't be able to generate WS client, so what use should I take from comments like **THE WSDL DOES NOT EXIST as a physical file!**? If you tell that this is automatic process please guide me how to generate this wsdl.xml file through some process?

Comment: An useful hint regards to PHP WSDL Cache. If your changes in wsdl does not take effects when testing it with other php, try to add ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0); to your php tester script. It helped me with a 3 hours debug.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing
I found the answer here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/web_services/overriding_an_existing_api_class_with_additional_functionality#wsdl

balexander: Your answer is really hostile!